# What’s this gold helmet piece and is it rare?

Tags: piece-information, piece-usage

[image]

I don’t know what this piece is and where it’s from

Answer (score 5):

That looks like a [Minifigure, Headgear Helmet Gladiator](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=95676&idColor=65#T=C&C=65)

I wouldn't call that piece rare.

Comment: However, it costs around 1 Euro, so don't be too careless with it.